# Dynamic date in highcharts tooltip

Tags: javascript, date, highcharts

I am trying to dynamically change the format of the date in a Highcharts graph, from the JSON input.

Basically I have data loaded from JSON and one of the values passed by JSON is also the date format, for example "%H %M". The reason for this is that I want the format to change dynamically based on the data passed to the series.

I came up with this code:

```
chart.series[0].update({
    tooltip:{
        pointFormat: '{series.name}{point.x}'+Highcharts.dateFormat('%e - %b - %Y','{point.x}')+'<b>{point.y}</b><br/>',
    }
});
```

In the above example, I intentionally inserted the point.x after the series name, just to check it contains the right value. It indeed does, it was a number in ms since Jan 1, 1970. However, for the date, it showed "Invalid date", even though when I tried hard-coding the same number there, it worked.

I then tried all sorts of combinations for the dateFormat function:

```
Highcharts.dateFormat('%e - %b - %Y',point.x)
Highcharts.dateFormat('%e - %b - %Y',eval('{point.x}'))
Highcharts.dateFormat('%e - %b - %Y',eval(point.x))
Highcharts.dateFormat('%e - %b - %Y',this.x)
Highcharts.dateFormat('%e - %b - %Y',eval('{this.x}'))
Highcharts.dateFormat('%e - %b - %Y',eval(this.x))
```

In case of the "point" I get invalid date, in case of using "this" I get an error.

But still, when I copy the same number which is the output of the {point.x} at the beginning, I get the correct date, this for example works:

```
Highcharts.dateFormat('%e - %b - %Y',1331942400000)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you provide this in jsfiddle ?

Comment: post your json which contains date sttring. is it in UTC or timestamp?

Comment: the data looks like this: "data":[[1333929600000,56.8907],[1334707200000,57.0751],[1335744900000,57.5473],...... the same number when hard coded in the dateFormat function works fine

Comment: Please recreate your example as live demo in the jsfiddle.net.